# Complex Analysis - Argument - Need Explanations

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

[image: Click Here For Image]

Can anyone explain this solution? How did we get $ - i(\pi/2 + 2n\pi) $?

Answer (score 0):

$-3i$ is a number on the negative imaginary axis. Its argument (angle with the positive real axis) is $-\frac{\pi}{2}+2n \pi$. Try to write $-3i$ in polar/trig form.

Now plug in your formula.
$$arg(-3i)=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2n \pi$$